# Buscar los múltiplos de un numero y sumarlos en Python

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, while

estoy arrancando en el tema de python y tengo un ejercicio que ya me rompió la cabeza. Seguro  es sencillo pero no encuentro el error. Tengo que buscar los números (con una función utilizando el loop while) en los cuales un numero (n) es divisible y sumarlos sin contar "n". es decir que si "n=8" debería dar 7 (1+2+4), pero me da 1. :(
Si alguien me da una mano se lo agradecería.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  div = 1
  if n==0:
   return 0
  elif n>0:
       while div<n:
          if n%div==0:
           sum=sum+div
           div+=1
           return sum
          else:
            div+=1
            return div
      
 
print(sum_divisors(8))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encuentro varios inconvenientes con tu código, el principal es que cuándo se encuentra una sentencia `return`, se *rompe* el ciclo en el que se encuentras, pues estás *ordenando* a la función que termine y retorne el valor.

Como inicias en 1 y *todos los números enteros positivos* son divisibles dentro de uno, la condición del `if n%div==0` siempre se cumplirá, se asigna 1 a sum y se retorna dicho valor, con lo cual la función siempre retorna 1 si le pasas un entero positivo.

Lo que en realidad quieres es retornar un valor solamente después de que termine el ciclo, así que la solución está en utilizar el ciclo solamente para ir acumulando el resultado y dejar una clausula `return` que se ejecute solo luego de que el ciclo haya terminado.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum = 0
        div = 1
        while div < n:
            if n%div==0:
                sum=sum+div
            div+=1
        return sum

print(sum_divisors(8))
```

He cambiado, además:

- La comparación del `if`, ya que la función retornará 0 si es cero y el resultado de la suma si es mayor que cero, pero no retornará nada si es menor que cero (lo hice por pura convención, quizás tu tengas que retornar algo diferente, pero se suele retornar algo.
- El lugar donde se inicializan `sum` y `div`, que no se usan antes
- El lugar donde se incrementa `div`, ya que se hace en cada iteración del ciclo, sin importar si el `divisor` cuenta o no.

En el futuro, para detectar este tipo de errores, puedes utilizar un editor que tenga un depurador integrado (se conocen como IDE de ***Entorno de Desarrollo Integrado*** (por sus siglas en inglés).

Dentro de un IDE puedes poner *breakpoints*, realizar la ejecución de tu código paso a paso (línea por línea, digamos), e ir viendo el valor de variables y como *salta* la ejecución de un punto a otro.

Comment: La verdad es que no se como agradecerte, te juro que se me caían las lagrimas cuando leía tu explicación, la cual fue más que suficiente para aclarar mis dudas. Espero algún día llegar a ser un crack como vos para poder colaborar en la pagina. Gracias amigo!!